# How to see the content of the ON-CHIP RAM of my design in DE1-SOC FPGA?

Tags: memory, fpga, ram, intel-fpga, synthesis

I have made a design in Quartus-II, on which I take an arrange of 57.600, 32 bits binary numbers, process it (some simple arithmetic) and then output another arrange of 57.600, 32 bits binary numbers (3 sets). For the input of data I used readmemb for the output I had to use the On-Chip Ram library megawizard.

Now I want to check the resulting data in the On-Chip RAM, I want to see if it produced the right results. What should I do? What is the most straightforward easy way to do it?

I also meant to replace the readmemb with another On-Chip RAM and initialize with a .MIF. my intention is to create a synthetizable design not only simulated.

My board is the DE1-SOC, is there any application to easy get this information?

Comment: For Quartus Prime, you can use In-System Memory Content Editor to check the content of the memory at runtime on the board. Not quite sure whether it is available in Quartus II though

Comment: Does this work also for SDRAM  not on-chip memory? if not, what would be the method?